# ASP.NET Response.BinaryWrite throws error in ie when creating Excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have a method that returns a byte array. I then write this array to the output stream as an excel file. Some users are reporting "Internet Explorer was not able to open this internet site" errors in ie7.

I don't get this error when I run it in the test environment (using ie9). However sometimes the first time I click the link, Excel will open but I'll receive an error the reads "there was a problem sending the command to the program" and the file doesn't load into Excel. If I click the link a second time, the file will open in Excel fine. Here's the code that send the byte array through the response stream, after the user clicks a link on a page.

```
byte[] buffer = GetBinary();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=xx.xls");
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.End();
```

If it makes any difference, the link they click opens up a new window, and the above block of code executes in the page_load event of the new page. What could be causing these errors? I've used similar code before with no issues.

Comment: I guess it can be something weird with Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString()), delete and try again.

Comment: Thanks but I actually added that after having the issue initially without it.